# How to limit current of a generator?

Tags: current, inverter, generator

I have a diesel generator that I’m feeding as backup power to a smart Growatt solar off-grid inverter.
The solar inverter accepts up to 100A input AC on 220V but the generator starts failing if it works at 100A. At 60A it works fine. So I’m wondering how could I limit the output current of the generator to 60A.

The inverter has the possibility of changing the input AC current. Unfortunately, it has, what I suppose it is a bug, in which the input AC current is fixed to 100A when using lithium batteries.

Comment: There are plenty of possibilities, but I would look at limiting the inverter's draw, not the generator's output.

Comment: It's already limiting itself.

Comment: You have only described two *sources*.  What are the *loads*?  That's probably where you need to manage the problem.  How are the generator and inverter interconnected?  Are they paralleled or is there a transfer switch?

Comment: There are off-the-shelf "controllers" available for off-grid power systems.  E.G., [This one](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B08R3MSXTG/). It's probably not big enough to meet your needs, but it illustrates the idea: It has terminals for mains power, solar panels, battery, and load, and it can be configured in various different ways of prioritizing which source powers the load depending on your objective.

Comment: Can you make a diagram of your system? No part of your question makes sense according to anything I know. I have never seen a 220 V DC generator. If it is AC, why would you feed AC to the input of a solar inverter? None of it makes any sense.

Comment: A 50 or 60 Amp fuse will limit the current of your generator to 50 or 60 Amps. If it exceeds 50 or 60 Amps for any length of time, the fuse will disconnect the load. I do not recommend using any other type of current limiting on a normal 220 VAC generator (assuming this is a 220 VAC generator). Well, you could use a circuit breaker instead of a fuse.

Comment: @Theodore It is a Growatt smart inverter, it also charges the batteries, so the generator is plugged into input AC as a backup power source.

Comment: @mkeith The generator is not DC, it is AC. The generator is plugged into inverter input AC and is used as backup power to charge the batteries.

Comment: When you say "AC current is fixed to 100A when using lithium batteries", does this mean that the inverter will draw 100A from the generator just to charge the batteries?  Can you shed some of the inverter's loads?

Comment: @Theodore The lithium batteries are 'smart batteries' so they communicate through a rj45 port with the inverter and pass some configuration to it which can't be changed. I think that is ok for the maximum current, which is 100A, the battery limit, but it also freezes the AC input current to 100A, that is not what I want, I needed 60A in this configuration.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems that what you really need to do is limit the AC input current on the inverter system, not the output current on the generator.  Until you can get the manufacturer of the inverter or battery system to allow that, you are probably stuck.

Answer (score 3):

I know this first part seems off-topic, but it's actually the crux of your problem.

### Use approved equipment according to their instructions.

Every jurisdiction I am aware of requires that you use equipment approved by the jurisdiction for quality and reliability.  That means UL, CSA, BSI, TUV, etc. etc.

Particularly, the CE mark is only valid on items purchased from EU manufacturers with significant bricks-and-mortar business presence in the EU.  (which is to say, NOT companies whose factory is in China and their EU 'presence' is a drop-box in Hamburg).

*If you do this, the approved equipment will handle the generator issues for you, as it will be built (and certified) to do this.*

Hire a licensed electrician and system integrator if you need help with this.  An electrician is not an electrical engineer, but a person who specializes in working with household/commercial AC power.

Looking at the Google results for this item, it appears to be cheap Chinese that is not in any way whatsoever certified to any western safety standard.  Three individual wires coming through a hole into 3 screw-down terminals, with no raceway or strain relief - that's not UL White Book and I'm sure it won't pass muster under European standards either.

---

The documentation for these units is extremely ambiguous, and full of "Engrish".  And it does not cover some of the use-cases claimed in the sales literature, including yours.  The unit appears to be extremely poorly supported. *But I guess that's why you're here, right?*

So this seems like a support issue from the company, and I would either turn to the manufacturer or your seller for support.  If that support is nonexistent, your best bet may be to send it back and buy from a company which has a support department.  Like Schneider.

I did notice they claim a 10-20 millisecond switchover time from running "on utility" to running "on inverter".  That suggests to me that it has a UPS-like relay that switches between the two.  If the inverter accepts generator output as valid grid power (big if), then it will have switched over to "utility" (read: generator) and will be passing generator power straight through.  **So it doesn't appear to blend**: the output is either on generator, or inverter, it is not mixing inverter with generator.  Thus the loads driven by the inverter are part of the total load on the generator.

I am very surprised to hear of a battery charger drawing 100A of 230V. That is a staggering amount of power for a battery charger (23KVA), and a battery would need to be very large (Tesla car?) to accept charge that fast.

### PSA: "Grid Tie" inverters won't play with a generator

The vast majority of solar inverters, and all "micro inverter" solar panels, are "grid-tie" / "grid-following".  They are designed to monitor/test for the characteristics of a stable utility grid, **and only generate when that grid is present**. That is so do not 'back feed' onto the grid and electrocute linemen trying to repair the lines.

People sometimes try to use a small generator to trick *grid-tie inverters / microinverters* into powering up and augmenting the generator.  Forget it - it will never work. The panels are not fooled.  Generator power is too irregular, and the loads do not have an impedance anything like a grid. Also, the solar inverter is generating only 240V - which will not feed 120V properly at all - the grid-tie inverters expect there to be a utility pole top transformer which would derive two poles of 120V from the 240V.

For that to work, you need a **grid forming inverter** which is specifically designed to spoof those grid-tie inverters into powering up.

Comment: The first part is definitely on-topic, and as you say, the crux.  The other two parts turn out to be off-topic as OP has clarified it's an off-grid system with batteries.

Comment: @Theodore OK I cleaned that up a lot. Got rid of the no-battery section.

Answer (score 3):

Current limiting on generators is only useful in special occasions. This is not one of them. In fact, it's even dangerous.

Current limiting, if implemented, is done by the voltage regulator. It will lower the voltage, and then typically ohms law applies and the current reduces.

Reasons where current limit is used:

- Motor starts, big motors that take many seconds to come to speed. Of course during this the voltage will drop a lot. For example, big pumps at water processing plants and their emergency generators.
- Transformer in-rush testing, the same reason as above. Brand new or long time unused big transformers require magnetization current, you can't do that direct online. Rentals with current limit enabled are used for this.

**Reasons why it's dangerous in other places**:

- Current will also be limited in a short circuit. This will prevent fuses or circuit breakers from tripping, never clearing the short circuit causing fire.
- Inverters don't follow ohms law properly, they will want to convert the same power, and therefor the current will increase regardless. So it won't even work.

What you want to do:

- Power limit the inverter.
- Speed droop the motor, so the inverter trips out at some point.

Answer (score 1):

Realistically, you can't limit the current without the voltage and/or frequency collapsing.

A fuse or circuit breaker would protect the generator, but that's a rather extreme form of current limiting.